# Haskell error: Couldn't match expected type `Bool' against inferred type `IO b'

Tags: haskell, monads, boolean

I do not understand what the problem is. 'a' is not a bool and should not be a bool. So why is bool expected?

Code:

```
probablyPrime n 0 = False
probablyPrime n t =
      do a <- randomRIO(3, n-1 :: Integer)      
         let comp = defComp(a,n)     
         let ret  = (not comp) && (probablyPrime n t-1)
         return ret


defComp a n = xcon1 && xcon2
where (s,m) = findsm n
      x = a^m `mod` n
      xcon1 = x /= 1 || x /= n-1
      xcon2 = comploop x n s


comploop x n 0 = False
comploop x n s = x1 || (comploop x n (s-1))
    where x1 = (x^2 `mod` n) == 1


findsm n = (s,m)
where m = findm n
      s = n/m


findm n = m
  where f = (logBase 2 n) - (truncate (logBase 2 n))
        m' = 2^f
        m = m_ify m'


m_ify m | m mod 1 == 0 = m
     | otherwise = m_ify (m*2)
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Bool' against inferred type `IO b'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
    a <- randomRIO (3, n - 1 :: Integer)
In the expression:
    do { a <- randomRIO (3, n - 1 :: Integer);
         let comp = defComp ...;
         let ret = (not comp) && (probablyPrime n t - 1);
         return ret }
In the definition of `probablyPrime':
    probablyPrime n t
                    = do { a <- randomRIO (3, n - 1 :: Integer);
                           let comp = ...;
                           let ret = ...;
                           .... }
```

Comment: You need to be careful of your function-call syntax. You use `f(x,y)` several times, but this is almost never right in Haskell -- it applies the function to a single tuple; you want `f x y`.

Comment: (actually, to be more precise, you *do* want it for `randomRIO` but not `defComp`)

Comment: Isn't there a basic problem with the logic here? If you're `&&`-ing `probablyPrime n t` all the way down to `t = 0` and `probablyPrime  n 0` is `False`, then you'll always get `False`.

Comment: You'll also need to add `fromIntegral` in a few places to get the numeric types right. `logBase` takes `Fractional` arguments, for example, while `mod` needs `Integral`, and nothing is an instance of both.

Answer (score 5):

```
probablyPrime n 0 = False
```

This tells haskell that the return type of `probablyPrime` is `Bool`. However in the second case, you're dealing with monads and returning `IO Bool`, so the types don't match.

Change `False` to `return False` and it will work.

You will also have to change

```
let ret  = (not comp) && (probablyPrime n t-1)
```

to

```
prob <- probablyPrime n (t-1)
let ret = (not comp) && prob
```

or something like

```
ret <- liftM ((not comp) &&) (probablyPrime n (t-1))
```

as Andrew Jaffe pointed out.

Comment: But the line `let ret  = (not comp) && (probablyPrime n t-1)` implies a `Bool` return for `probablyPrime`, so that expression needs to be lifted into the monad, too (right?).

Comment: I'm talking about its appearance on the RHS -- `(&&)` is `Bool->Bool->Bool`.

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, bah, of course. I didn't think/read properly. Yes, that needs to be lifted.

Comment: It should also be `probablyPrime n (t-1)`. Haskell's whitespace is significant, but not *that* significant.

Answer (score 3):

The type of probablyPrime should be IO Bool, so your first pattern match should lift the pure value of False into the IO monad using return function, basically change:

```
probablyPrime n 0 = False
```

to

```
probablyPrime n 0 = return False
```

You cannot esacpe the IO monad without using unsafe functions but you should not do this unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. Does my code escape the IO monad, or do you mean that I should just not try it?

Comment: Andreas Sjöström@ No but it kind of looks like you were trying with the first pattern match. the haskell runtime & OS will execute IO actions using the main function. There are ways to force an escape of the IO monad but you should very rarely need to do this if ever. This isn't usually the case of other monads like state monad.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to avoid `IO` whenever you can, and using the `State` monad provides a convenient way to do so here:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import Control.Monad (liftM, replicateM)
import Control.Monad.State (State, evalState, get, put)
import System.Random

probablyPrime :: RandomGen g => Int -> Int -> State g Bool
probablyPrime t = liftM and . replicateM t . checkOnce
  where
    checkOnce :: RandomGen g => Int -> State g Bool
    checkOnce n = do
      (a, gen) <- randomR (3, n - 1) <$> get
      put gen
      return . not $ defComp a n

defComp = undefined
```

To test whether a number is (probably) prime you do the following (note that I've changed the order of the arguments to `probablyPrime`, since `t` is less likely to vary than `n`):

```
evalState (probablyPrime 10 7057) <$> newStdGen :: IO Bool
```

This allows you to avoid stepping into `IO` until it's absolutely necessary.